# Delete all classes with fewer than three ships. Note that the "Bismarck" class has no ship, therefore the class should be removed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

[I tried to delete all the class that has fewer than 3 ships but I can't delete the Bismarck which has no ship. I can't figure out how to delete it does anybody know what I did wrong? The answer below is what i have try to input][image: 1]

Table

```
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
Ships(name, class, launched)
Battles(name, date)
Outcomes(ship, battle, result)
```

My Answer

```
DELETE FROM classes WHERE class IN 
  (SELECT class FROM ships 
   GROUP BY class HAVING Count(name) < 3) AND NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM ships);
```

Comment: what do you mean by you can't remove? are you getting an error message? add the error messsge to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use not exists to delete all the classes which don't exist in Ships table with no less than 3 ships.

```
delete from Classes
where not exists 
                (
                  select class from Ships group by class having count(*)>=3
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DELETE FROM classes WHERE
    (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from ships s WHERE s.`class` = classes.`class` )) OR
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) from ships s WHERE s.`class` = classes.`class`) < 3)
```